# The sql works fine but with python it doesn't insert values into table

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, commit, sql-insert, psycopg2

I'm trying to use python for stored procs in sql, I have tested my sql code and it works fine, but when I execute it via python, the values are not inserted into my table
Note: I don't have any errors when executing

My code below:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname'
                    , host='host'
                    , port='5439', user='username', password='password')

def executeScriptsfromFile(filename):
    #Open and read the file as a single buffer
    cur = con.cursor()
    fd = open(filename,'r')
    sqlFile = fd.read()
    fd.close()

    #all SQL commands(split on ';')
    sqlCommands = filter(None,sqlFile.split(';'))

    #Execute every command from the input file
    for command in sqlCommands:
        # This will skip and report errors
        # For example, if the tables do not yet exist, this will skip over
        # the DROP TABLE commands
         try:
            cur.execute(command)
            con.commit()
         except Exception as inst:
            print("Command skipped:", inst)

    cur.close()
executeScriptsfromFile('filepath.sql')
```

Insert comment in sql:

```
INSERT INTO schema.users
SELECT
    UserId 
    ,Country 
    ,InstallDate
    ,LastConnectDate
    FROM #Source;
```

Note: As I said the sql works perfectly fine when I tested it.

Comment: Are you sure filepath.sql has something in it?

Comment: Post the `insert` command

Comment: @Tanveer Yes, I'm sure. I printed the top 10 results of each table and they're all good

Comment: Splitting the input on semicolons will remove the semicolons, so the individual commands may not be recognized as complete when they are executed.  You can try printing out cur.rowcount() after each execute command to see if anything is actually happening.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I added a print command after the try and everything seems to be executed. I think it's a commit issue, as only the part where it has to insert into a permanent table is not working